# Groovy Query builder request parameter error for Nexus folders

Tags: groovy, nexus, query-builder

I am writing query for getting Nexus assets in groovy

```
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier().get();
tx.begin();

tx.findAssets(Query.builder()
.where('name like ').param('v2/%')
.build(), [repo]).each { asset ->
log.info("Print - ${asset.name()}");
```

if I put in parameters `'v2/%'` - some path in Nexus -  then it works correctly.
If I put some variable - like this

```
def item ="abc";
tx.findAssets(Query.builder()
.where('name like ').param('v2/${item}/%')
.build(), [repo]).each { asset ->
log.info("Print - ${asset.name()}");
```

I get exception:

```
"Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Negative array index [-1] too large for array size 0
2018-04-30 18:50:51,105+0000 ERROR [quartz-5-thread-4]  *SYSTEM java.lang.Throwable - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Negative array index [-1] too large for array size 0"
```

Why it happens like this?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you would need to use a GString (`"v2/${item}/%"`) if you expect variable substitution: e.g.

```
def item ="abc";
tx.findAssets(Query.builder()
  .where('name like ').param("v2/${item}/%")
  .build(), [repo]).each { asset ->
log.info("Print - ${asset.name()}");
```

Comment: hmm, that's the way how I am doing it now. But it does NOT work.

Comment: your example was 'v2/${item}/%' - interpolation requires double-quotes not single quotes. ie. "v2/${item}/%"  - http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string